# Windows phone 7 binding color to textbox

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, data-binding, mvvm

I am new to Windows Phone,
I am trying to bind SolidColorBrush property to texbox foreground. 
XAML :

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Sober, StringFormat=t}" Foreground="{Binding Path=SoberColor, Mode=OneWay}" TextAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}"/>
```

ViewModel:

```
private SolidColorBrush _soberColor;
    public SolidColorBrush SoberColor
    {
        get { return _soberColor; }
        set
        {
            _soberColor = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("SoberColor");
        }
    }
```

I am doing it according this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/6459988a-cbb7-418e-9589-45a2a8cb8f41/foreground-color-change?forum=wpdevelop) .

But it just doesn't work and color is still black. I've debugged it and SoberColor contains value 
`SoberColor = new SolidColorBrush(new Color { R = 245, G = 171, B = 0 });`
Other property bindings from same page and same viewmodel work, only this one doesn't...
Am I doing something wrong or this kind of binding should be done in different way?
Thanks

Comment: Instead of your R-245 G-171 B-0, use the hex equivalent (#F5AB00) or the string equivalent (orange.)

Comment: Thanks man, I finally used `new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 245, 171, 0));` and it works

Comment: @Maarty you can add it as an answer and accept it, it would be helpful to others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally used `new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 245, 171, 0));` and it works